# Unable to show OpenStreepMap in Tizen wearable web application

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap, tizen, tizen-web-app

I'm trying to open *OpenStreetMap* with *OpenLayers* on a wearable simulator using *Tizen*.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
   <title>Circular UI</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (-tizen-geometric-shape: circle)" 
href="lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.circle.min.css">
   <!-- load theme file for your application -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
<body>
<div class="ui-page ui-page-active" id="main">
  <header class="ui-header">
    <h2 class="ui-title">TAU Basic</h2>
  </header>
  <div class="ui-content content-padding">
    <p>test </p>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  <script src="ol.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/tau/wearable/js/tau.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="lowBatteryCheck.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
$(function(){
  new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()})
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    }),
    target: 'map' 
});
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/OSMOL" 
version="1.0.0" viewmodes="maximized">
  <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
  <access origin="http://openlayers.org/" subdomains="true"/>
  <access origin="https://openstreetmap.org/" subdomains="true"/>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.normal"/>
  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <name>OSMOL</name>
  <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
  <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
  <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/filesystem.read"/>
  <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/filesystem.write"/>
  <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/location.gps"/>
  <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/location"/>
  <tizen:profile name="wearable"/>
  <tizen:setting hwkey-event="enable"/>
</widget>
```

Map is showing when testing the code in a normal web application, but when running with Tizen as a wearable map, it is not showing.

I get this error while debugging:

> GET https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/2/1/1.png
>   net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED c.tile.openstreetmap.org/2/2/2.png:1
>   GET https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/2/2/2.png
>   net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED b.tile.openstreetmap.org/2/1/2.png:1
>   GET 
>   ***2 more of the same, cant post due reputation***

I think it's an issue in **config.xml** with access. I've tried lots of things, including adding these links to `<access origin>`. Nothing works and I'm completely stuck.

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add your ol.js after Jquery but before app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it seems that Tizen somehow blocks the normal OL CDN, use this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/4.1.1/ol.js"</script>
```

instead and it should be working fine!

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

What about running it on emulator ? I suspect connectivity issues

when I started to port a mobile app to wearable, I think it worked without black magic:

https://github.com/tizenteam/mapo/tree/tizen-2.3-wearable